# how to receive alarm service extending main activity

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-alarms

I need help in receiving an alarm service. Its not that easy as it seems as i need not only the variables but data to pass on to the onReceive
Heres the broadcast receiver which is IN THE MAIN ACTIVITY. i created a class inside the main activity so the variables could be intact. its not only the variables

```
  public class MyBroadcastReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(1990, 1, 1, hour, minute);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
        String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        String str=date.charAt(0)+""+date.charAt(1)+""+date.charAt(3)+""+date.charAt(4);
        minochaDevicePolicyManager.resetPassword(str,0);
    }
}
```

I am instantiating minochaDevicePolicyManager in the main activity onCreate. Here

```
minochaDevicePolicyManager=(DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
```

Now the task here is to create a class named MyBroadcastReceiver where the receiver will work. cuz it is dependent of the MainActivity. its more like an extension of mainactivity
help

Comment: Hey @codeMagic it is clearly written that the help needed is to create a class named MyBroadcastReceiver where the receiver will work. the receive method is there. the reason it cant work is that it is in the mainactivity. and i have no idea how to take it out of the main activity without affecting its task. if you try to remove it just like that there will be many errors like minochaDevicePolicyAdmin is not resolved and even if you get it the context isnt present.

Comment: One solution is to create a constructor in your new class and pass `minochaDevicePolicyManager` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `onReceive()` has a parameter which is a `Context`. You can use this to obtain the `DevicePolicyManager` from within `onReceive()`:

```
DevicePolicyManager minochaDevicePolicyManager
    = (DevicePolicyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
```

Other data that is required in `onReceive()` should be sent via the `Intent` which is broadcast from the `Activity`.

Comment: So what should finally be my Mybroadcast receiver?
and what is the other data?

Comment: @Rishabh Add the line given in my answer before you use `minochaDevicePolicyManager` in `onReceive()`. You can remove this variable from `MainActivity`. As for the "other data", it is any information that the `BroadcastReceiver` gets from the `MainActivity` or any other external source. Look at any variables that give compiler errors when you extract the `BroadcastReceiver` to an external class. These will give you a clue.

Comment: Hey, It doesn't work. I gave it a try. Could you help me with the code?

Comment: @Rishabh Please edit your question with the details of what you have tried.

Comment: @Rishabh After a closer look at your code, I don't see any data that you need to send with an Intent. You just have to be careful about where you declare your variables.

Comment: @Rishabh Also, I noticed a typo in my answer. It is fixed now.